# How to judge performance of algorithms for Text Clustering?

Tags: cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means, document-classification

I am using K-Means algorithm for Text Clustering with initial seeding with K-Means++.

I try to make the algorithm more efficient with some changes like changing the stop-word dictionary and increasing the max_no_of_random_iterations.

I get different results. How do i compare them ? I could not apply the idea of confusion matrix here. Output is not in the form of some document getting some value or tag. A document goes to a set. It is just relative "good clustering" or the set that matters.

So Is there some standard way for marking the performance for this output set ?

If confusion matrix is the answer, please explain how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason for the c++ tag here, is there?

Comment: You can only quantify the "fitness" of a cluster if you know how you want things to be clustered. It's usually an *unsupervised* algorithm.

Comment: i have some small set of documents and testing on it. i know the perfect set of each document, so if i could compare to it, it would be great.

Comment: There are various methods for comparing two clusterings. Have you tried them on your test set then?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I do not know about these methods. Can you please provide some links ?

Comment: Read the cluster analysis article on Wikipedia. It discusses external evaluation, too.

Comment: If you are using weka, you can use classes to cluster evaluation cluster test mode which gives you confusion matrix

Answer (score 0):

You could decide in advance how to measure the quality of the clusters, for example count how many empty ones or some stats like  *Within Sum of Squares*

This [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.119.3942&rep=rep1&type=pdf) says

> "... three  distinctive approaches to cluster validity are possible. 
>   The first approach relies on **external criteria** that investigate the
>   existence of some predefined structure in  clustered data set. The
>   second approach makes use of **internal criteria** and the clustering
>   results are evaluated  by quantities describing the data set such as
>   proximity  matrix etc.  Approaches based on internal and external
>   criteria make use of statistical tests and their disadvantage is 
>   high computational cost. The third approach makes use of **relative
>   criteria** and relies on finding the best clustering scheme that meets
>   certain assumptions and requires predefined input parameters values"

Since clustering  is *unsupervised*, you are asking for something difficult. I suggest researching how people cluster using genetic algorithms and see what fitness criteria they use.